# Converting Home Movies to DVD using Windows Media Center?

Tags: windows-7, windows-media-center

When I use Windows Media Center on Windows 7 to record my old home videos on to DVD, the VCR is on channel 3.

However, when I try to record them, the scheduling application makes the recording stop within the allotted time period of whatever happens to be on tv at the moment on channel 3 according to my cable provider.

So what do I need to do to be able to record, and just keep recording until I press the stop button?  My home movies are on hour and a half tapes.

I realize that I could just wait until something is on that is an hour and a half, but I have stacks of these things my mother wants converted to DVD, it's just not practical.

Comment: What type of video capture card ( make and model) are you using?

Comment: @RSMoser Hauppauge! WinTV-HVR-1950 (external)

Comment: The problem is that the recorder thinks it's recording off of cable, but it isn't, it's recording off of my VHS player.

Comment: How is the scheduling app getting the TV programing?  Might try to disable it.

Comment: @RSMoser It's built in to Windows-Media-Center for Windows 7.  When you setup the cable, it asks you what your zipcode is, and you tell it your cable provider.

Me, I just wanna change channels, and I wanna just press record, and when the VHS tape finishes press stop.  Is there a way to disable it?

Answer (score 0):

does the dvd recorder have a COAX jack or an AV (the red yellow and white chords not sure if AV is the correct termonology) if it has AV hook it to the vcr and from the vcr put the channle of input (sometimes called game) see if this helps, if not, have you considered hooking the vcr to your pc?